# The program repeats until the input string is quit and disregards the integer input that follows

Tags: python, loops, conditional-statements, break

Write a program that takes a string and an integer as input, and outputs a sentence using the input values as shown in the example below. The program repeats until the input string is quit and disregards the integer input that follows.

Ex: If the input is:

```
apples 5
shoes 2
quit 0
```

the output is:

```
Eating 5 apples a day keeps the doctor away.
Eating 2 shoes a day keeps the doctor away.
```

This is what I've got so far:

```
string = input().split()
string2 = input().split()
string3 = input().split()

all_input = (string + string2 + string3)

for word in all_input:
    while word != 'quit':
        print('Eating {} {} a day keeps the doctor away.'.format(string[1] , string[0]))
        print('Eating {} {} a day keeps the doctor away.'.format(string2[1], string2[0]))
        string = input().split()
        string2 = input().split()
        string3 = input().split()
        all_input = (string + string2 + string3)
```

I get the correct output but also receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
    string = input().split()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

And when it tests with the inputs:

```
cars 99
quit 0
```

Then I get no output. I feel like I need to use a break statement somewhere but nowhere I put it seems to work.

Comment: You are taking 3 input and gave only two input then how will you getting output. Are you trying to break the program if quit is written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using `input()` multiple times where you can use it once inside a loop and if the `input_string` contains '**quit**' it will be terminated. try the following code, it will continue taking input till the user enters **quit**

```
while True:
    input_string = input()
    if 'quit' in input_string:
        break
    else:
        a,b = input_string.split(' ')
        print(f'Eating {b} {a} a day keeps the doctor away.')
```

## OR

if you want to take all inputs at once, then find the code below, it will work as you expected

```
input_string = []
while True:
    line = input()
    if 'quit' in line:
        break
    else:
        input_string.append(line)

for line in input_string:
    a,b = line.split(' ')
    print(f'Eating {b} {a} a day keeps the doctor away.')
```

Comment: I just get this error when I tried this:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    a,b = input_string.split(' ')
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: are you trying to enter multiple words in single line? `a,b = input_string.split(' ')` can take two words in single line.....like apples 5, quit 0 etc.

Comment: It is putting each input on different lines like in my OP with apples 5, shoes 2 and then quit 0. That why I thought I had to use more than one input.

Comment: do want to read all input at once? and then show all output at once?

Comment: @Tyler I added another answer

Comment: That works! Thank you. I just have no idea whyyyy it works

Comment: @Tyler, In this code, I am taking input till the user enters 'quit'. I also appended all the strings in a list namely `input_string` as we can easily iterate a list. Then using the for loop, iterating over the list where all my inputs are stored, for each line of input, splitting each line using **space** as we have two values in each line, for example, apples 5, assigning `a=apples` and `b=5`, then printing the output as expected. Still, if you have any confusion, don't hesitate to ask me. If this solution satisfies your requirements, don't forget to mark this answer as solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop to achieve the same result, and you can use it too for files with more and less lines.

You can use `'quit' not in variable_name` as the exit condition of the loop.  When the variable you test is a substing, this statement will look for "quit" as a substring.

To split the words in the lines [str.split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) is your friend. After calling it, it returns an array. The first element of this array will be the object, and the second the number of elements.

```py
mad_lib = input()

while 'quit' not in mad_lib:
    MD_list = mad_lib.split()
    thing = MD_list[0]
    integer = MD_list[1]
    print("Eating {} {} a day keeps the doctor away.".format(integer,thing))
    
    # Read the input again to process more lines
    mad_lib = input()
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and add some commentary to explain your code. Do not expect everyone to understand what you have posted. Explanations are key.

Answer (score 0):

The main roadblock may be splitting the input first, as others noted. Additionally, do not think of this exercise as there will be a set number of strings. Strings can be 0 to infinity -- that will be left to the user (or computer) to decide. Once you `str.split()` and loop input before the loop and in the loop, you can KISS (keep it simple stupid) with a **not in** rather than using breaks. Sure, the breaks look as if you paid attention during your lessons in the chapter, though so far I have found breaks to be only needed under select circumstances (if at all?). If your instructor does not have requirements on what you need to use in your program, use the following (also seen in @Jamal McDaniel / @Iñigo González above).

```
user_input = input()  #initial input

while 'quit' not in user_input:
    choices = user_input.split()  #split the string
    word = choices[0]
    integer = choices[1]
    print("Eating {} {} a day keeps the doctor away.".format(integer, word))
    user_input = input()  #get another input and loop until 'quit'
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using this code.

```
var1 = input()     #takes in string(apples 5)
mad_lib = var1.split()  #splits user input into two strings (apples, 5)



while 'quit' not in mad_lib:     #loop that only stops when 'quit' is entered
    print('Eating {} {} a day keeps the doctor away.'.format(mad_lib[1], mad_lib[0]))
    var1 = input()       #increments loop with new input(shoes 2)
    mad_lib = var1.split()     #splits new user input into two strings again (shoes, 2)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).